# PHP 7.4 errors, Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in

Tags: php

I hope this doesn't get flagged as duplicate because I read the other posts and they are all very different and there's no one-size fits all answer for every situation.

I have two scripts returning this error and I need some help please.

The code for the first one that's returning this error is this one...

```
    function getCompanyName($company_id)
{
    $company_id = $this->db->escape($company_id);
    $result = $this->db->query("SELECT company_name FROM companies WHERE idx='$company_id'");
    $data = $result->fetch();

    return $this->db->escape($data['company_name']);
}
```

It's that last return line that's giving me the error and I don't know how to rewrite it.

The other script is giving me the following error...

```
Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool in /home/example.php(3) : eval()'d code on line 20
```

My full php script with line 20 looks like this...

```
foreach ($valid_numbers as $number) {
    $Sid          = $number->sid;
    $FriendlyName = Util::escapeString($number->friendly_name);
    $PhoneNumber  = $number->phone_number;
    $VoiceUrl     = $number->voice_url;
    $SmsUrl     = $number->sms_url;

if(!Util::isNumberIntl($PhoneNumber))
{
    $phone_number = Util::format_phone_us($PhoneNumber);
    $company_name = $db->getCompanyName($db->getCompanyOfNumber($db->format_phone_db($PhoneNumber)));
}else{
    $phone_number = format_phone($db->format_phone_db($PhoneNumber));
    $company_name = $db->getCompanyName($db->getCompanyOfNumber(substr($PhoneNumber,1,(strlen($PhoneNumber)-1))));
}

$number_details = $db->getOutgoingNumberDetails($db->format_phone_db($PhoneNumber));

if ($number_details['pool_id'] == 0 || empty($number_details['pool_id'])) {
```

And that final line with the "if" statement is what's throwing off that error.

So anyone can help me how to fix these two instances?

Thanks again for your valuable contributions to this forum!

Jim

Comment: Is the return of `getCompanyName` going into SQL? You should use `var_dump` to see what your values are.

Comment: `0` is considered empty, so you don't need the `== 0` test.

Comment: The error means that `$number_details` isn't an array.

Comment: What does `getCompanyName` have to do this with this? The problem is related to the phone number, not the company name.

Comment: The error means that `$number_details` is either `TRUE` or `FALSE`. I suspect `getOutgoingNumberDetails()` returns `FALSE` if it can't get the details.

Comment: _"...there's no one-size fits all answer..."_ - actually, there is. And that's finding out what returned a boolean where you were expecting an array. Don't try to find a solution to fix the symptom, fix the cause.